# sql error on select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a select query for retriving data on mssql server 2008,
 eg : `select * from abc`

but its getting error is

> Internal error. Buffer provided to read column value is too small. Run DBCC CHECKDB to check for any corruption.

how can i override this error..?

Comment: Did you run `DBCC CHECKDB` ?

Comment: And perhaps give us some column definitions, given that the error refers to a column problem.

Comment: no @ gordon Linoff

Comment: @SalmaanC  Just a shot in the dark here, but you might try running [**`DBCC CheckDB`**](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/05/dbcc-checkdb-faq/) to check for any corruption.

Comment: how can i perform that........?@sqlZim

Answer (score 0):

I have this error exactly because I restarted or stopped sql service while doing work, it caused some data corruption.

```
Internal error. Buffer provided to read column value is too small. Run DBCC CHECKDB to check for any corruption.
```

Just run `DBCC CHECKDB` once and wait to check for any corruption and fix them, then when the query finish repairing can use any query you want.